# Обновления таблицы с таймером

Tags: ios, swift, время

В моей таблице находятся таймеры, скажем, 2 таймера, помимо таймеров в таблице находятся картинки. Когда я обновляю таблицу - `reloadData()` (для обновления таймера), то мои картинки, находящиеся в кеше, начинают мерцают. Как мне обновить таблицу без мерцаний картинок?

Comment: код какой нибудь покажете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы картинки не мерцали, не нужно их обновлять. Этого можно избежать, если, например, сравнивать текущее значение `imageView.image` с новым (не будет работать, если картинка каждый раз загружается).

Вообще, по-правильному это делается так: для ячеек создается модельный объект, который хранит в себе данные для всех элементов ячеек. Тогда можно в коде обновления ячейки можно будет эффективно проверять данные на различие и избежать переприсвоения тех данных, которые не изменились.

Comment: А нет ли примера какого-нибудь посмотреть? Просто у меня сейчас реализована проверка на кэш, т.е. если есть что-то в кэше, то буру из него, если нет, то делаю запрос. У меня в этой таблице еще подключен таймер и чтобы обновлять время, мне приходится обновлять таблицу, было бы очень интересно посмотреть на то как можно обновить таймер, не обновляя всей таблицы

Comment: Идея не в том, чтобы не обновлять таблицу, а в том, чтобы обновлять только таймеры. Проблема вашего подхода в слишком частом обновлении `imageView`, из-за этого происходит мерцание. Если картинки не меняются (они ведь не меняются?), то обновлять их каждый раз нет смысла.
Примера кода под рукой нет, но я могу показать на вашем коде что нужно улучшить, чтобы добиться хорошего результата.

Comment: Да, верно, они не меняются. Спасибо, сегодня попробую реализовать

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Чтобы не обновлять всю таблицу, обновлял только те ячейки, которые мне были нужны, а чтобы картинки на мерцали, просто убирал анимацию: (UITableViewRowAnimation.None)